# Can I force all applications to use one device for sound output?

Tags: gnome, sound

I use my laptop on its own, with a speakerless monitor, with a monitor with speakers, with headphones, with a wireless headset...  My frustration is that different applications seem to output their stuff to different sound devices and there doesn't seem to be a single way to say "output sound here".  The GNOME Sound settings is ignored by some apps, e.g. Zoom.  I have between 1 and 6 devices appearing at various times.  The GNOME sound icon in the top bar doesn't actually do anything.

I can work around all this by running `pavucontrol` (Pulse Audio Volume Control) - here I can direct applications to the device I want (although only if they're playing at the time).  And I can set the volumes of the different devices.

What I would like is:

- a unified way to tell all apps AT ONCE to "use device X"
- the GNOME sound icon/widget at the top right to actually work

My laptop is running Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS with GNOME 42.9